# Is there anything wrong with the program

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  char sor[6] = "hello";
  char des[6] = "hello";
  strcat(des,sor);
  cout << des;
}
```

When i start the debugging of the program it gives the following error along with the console output *(behind it)* :
[image]

**why is it so ?** If there is anything wrong with the code ,please give a suggestion

Comment: try to allocate large memory before using arrays that should be greater than or equal to 11. Hope this helps

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. Is it?

Comment: @ Alf P. Steinbach no not all..i was trying something else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While increasing the size of the <s>string</s> char-array would help you in this situation, let me propose to actually use C++ features; don't code C when you want to code C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  string sor = "hello";
  string des = "hello";
  des += sor;
  cout << des;
}
```

## Why not char arrays

Suhail asked why char-arrays are bad:

One shouldn't be using char-arrays because of situations like exactly this. Many more dangerous situations exist; effectively, when you are using C arrays, there's a certain danger that your program is subject to buffer-overflow attacks.

You were actually very lucky that you directly received the exception; but more often than you like those bugs are subtle and don't uncover themselves for days, months, years; and then, possibly, your customer will be in in the daily news for being cracked and losing their customers credit card information into the public.

Using C++ facilities like `string` or `stringstream`, this can be avoided easily.

---

- [Buffer Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) (for examples, check the [history section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow#History))
- [Format String Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format_string_attack) (not directly related to specifically this question, but another example of char-array vulnerabilities and using C instead of C++)

Answer (score 4):

`Des` isn't large enough to hold the result after concatenation. You should increase the size of the array.

Comment: No, he should not be using char arrays.

Comment: @ phresnel why i should not be using char arrays?

Comment: I dnt think char arrays have problem

Comment: @Suhail Gupta, @asma: One shouldn't be using char-arrays because of situations like exactly this. Many more dangerous situations exist; effectively, when you are using C arrays, there's a certain danger that your program is subject to buffer-overflow attacks. You were lucky that you directly received the exception; but more often than you like those bugs are subtle and don't uncover themselves for days, months, years; and then, possibly, your customer will be in in the daily news for being cracked and losing their customers credit card information.

Comment: I actually have to agree with phresnel about not using char array for such a purpose. But in this case, the OP wants to know why the problem is occurring with the code. Therefore my answer was focused on that instead of suggesting alternative coding.

Answer (score 1):

`des` has only space for 6 bytes and you are trying to fit 11 bytes 5+5+1 in it:

```
'h'+'e'+'l'+'l'+'o'+'h'+'e'+'l'+'l'+'o'+'\0'
```

this results in corrupting the stack ( since des is an automatic variable ) this is the reason the cout works but the program crash as soon it try to return.
It works if you declare `des[11]`.

Answer (score 0):

try to allocate memory before using arrays. Hope this helps
And as Gunner suggested, try to allocate memory according to the size of what you are going to put in arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`strcat` appends the second parameter to the end of the first. This means that in your case the total length of concatenation will be 11 characters, while `des` has only place enough to hold 6. Change `des[6]` to `des[11]` and your program will work fine. Also check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/) reference for more information about `strcat`.

Answer (score 0):

strcar concatenates the strings. you should verify there is enough space for this.
in your case - you've allocated memory for 6 chars when the concatenated string will have 11 chars (10 chars and \ in the end)